# Load a table from Google Storage to BigQuery using Google App Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I believe this is setting up the job configuration correctly, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get the the job to run.  Has anyone had success using Apps Script to load a table to BigQuery?

```
function testLoad(){

  var fields = [
    {'name': 'FirstName', 'type':'STRING'},
    {'name': 'LastName', 'type':'STRING'}
  ];

  var schema = BigQuery.newTableSchema()
    schema.setFields(fields)

  var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference()
    tableReference.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    tableReference.setDatasetId('Test_Dataset');
    tableReference.setTableId('TestTable1');

  var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
    load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
    load.setSkipLeadingRows(1);
    load.setSourceUris([SOURCE]);
    load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
    load.setSchema(schema)

  var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
    configuration.setLoad(load);

  var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
    newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

  var insert = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob)

  Logger.log(insert.getId());

}
```

Comment: looks good, what errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm getting "Required parameter is missing (line 58, file "Load")"  It's referring to the line just before the Logger.log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got back to this issue.  The missing piece was needing to include the project id to the insert job as well as the table reference.

I also included a bit to poll for the job status and return when the job is done.

```
function testLoad(){

  Logger.log(exampleLoad_());
}


function exampleLoad_(){

  try{

    var fields = [
      {'name': 'FirstName', 'type':'STRING'},
      {'name': 'LastName', 'type':'STRING'}
    ];

    var schema = BigQuery.newTableSchema();
    schema.setFields(fields);

    var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
    tableReference.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    tableReference.setDatasetId('Test_Dataset');
    tableReference.setTableId('TestTable1');

    var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
    load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
    load.setSkipLeadingRows('1');
    load.setSourceUris([SOURCE]);
    load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
    load.setSchema(schema);
    load.setAllowJaggedRows(false);

    var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
    configuration.setLoad(load);

    var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
    newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

    var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, {projectId:PROJECT_ID});

    var jobId = job.getJobReference().getJobId();

    var status = job.getStatus();


    while (status.getState() != 'DONE'){

      if(status.getState() == 'PENDING'){
        Utilities.sleep(100);

      }

      if (status.getErrorResult() == true){     
        return status.getErrors();

      } 
      status = BigQuery.Jobs.get(PROJECT_ID, jobId).getStatus();
    }

  }catch(err){ 
    return err;

  }

  return status.getState();
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this? I'm trying to use it, bug I can't.